# How to display QR code url image into pdf file?

Tags: image, pdf, textarea

Hey I have this textarea that makes the text into pdf when I press generate.

And now I want a qr code img to get added. The problem is the pdf can't detect it, but only make space for it.

Example if I add a img like:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"/>
```

it works.

But if I add something like

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=a,s,000000|bg,s,FFFFFF&chs=300x300&chld=M|4&cht=qr&chl=++++++++++++++++++++++++++++test%0A++++++++++++++++++++++&choe=UTF-8"/>
```

It wont work

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download it first into local disk, then you could write local address of that image in 'src='.

img src="http://localhost/blabla/image/chart.png"/>

Maybe its because your url isnt image, but php page. So pdf converter couldnt display it in to pdf.

Comment: Yea i thought about that. But i want a system that gives every person a different qr code. So i can't download it first. 

Like they write what they want their qr code to be and it gets inserted.

Comment: Then i cant help you, sorry. But if you still want to save it you can use this code : 
$filename = "./chart.png"; 
 if (!file_exists($filename)) { 
 $qr = file_get_contents("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=a,s,000000|bg,s,FFFFFF&chs=300x300&chld=M|4&cht=qr&chl=++++++++++++++++++++++++++++test%0A++++++++++++++++++++++&choe=UTF-8"); 
 file_put_contents($filename, $qr); 
 } 
 echo "<img src=\"$filename\" />";